# Problemas Conexion Bigquery con php

Tags: php

Buenos días me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar para hacer la conexión a *biguqery* con PHP.

Soy nuevo en el tema de consumo de api y la verdad, google no es que tenga información muy completa. Seguí los pasos que google me indica con el código pero me arroja el siguiente error de autentificación, pero no sé como autenticarme.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
>   "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required
>   authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie
>   or other valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
>   "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global",
>   "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType":
>   "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Este es  mi código que tengo actualmente los datos que me piden los coloque en 'xxxx' por seguridad gracias.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\core\ExponentialBackoff;


$projectId = "xxxxx";
$datasetId = "xxxxx";
$tableId    = "xxxxxxxx";
$source     = "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxx\xxxx";

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);

$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($tableId);

$loadConfig = $table->load(fopen($source, 'r'))->sourceFormat('CSV');

$job = $table->runJob($loadConfig);

$backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);

$backoff->execute(function()use ($job){
    printf('Waiting for job to complete'.PHP_EOL);
    $job->reload();
    if(!$job->isComplete()){
        throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
    }
});

if(isset($job->info()['status']['errorResult'])){
    $error = $job->info()['status']['errorResult']['message'];
    printf('Error running job: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error);
}else{
    print('Data imported successfully' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Comment: Por favor, añade tu código para completar la pregunta, solo con el error es imposible ayudarte

Comment: ya ingrese mi código gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

has mirado que tengas activa o creada el service account?? mira en este enlace: [service_account](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries?hl=es-419#client-libraries-install-php). Es esencial que tengas activo el serviceAccount, ya que es la manera de autenticar google una conexión por medio de una API con un usuario. Esto se hace en GCP, en el enlace tienes un enlace para crear tu service_account.

Además tiene un git bastante completo google para distintos lenguajes como Python, php o java de conexiones a sus APIs. Pásate por su git, te dejo aquí el enlace para bigQuery en php: [git_php](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/bigquery/api/src)